# Module build failed while importing svg file with react-svg-loader

Tags: reactjs

I have read through some implementations, but still can't figure out why I'm getting the following error, while trying to load an `.svg` file:

`ERROR in ./~/react-svg-loader/lib/loader.js?name=OfficeLayout!./assets/images/FLOOR_PLAN_OFF.svg
Module build failed: 
 @ ./shared/components/officeView/officeViewLayout.js 29:61-132`

In the `OfficeViewLayout` I'm just trying to import the file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import OfficeLayout from 'react-svg-loader!images/FLOOR_PLAN_OFF.svg';

export class OfficeViewLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="OfficeViewLayout">
        <OfficeLayout/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I want to use this component in the `OfficeView` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { OfficeViewLayout } from './officeViewLayout';

export class OfficeView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <OfficeViewLayout/>
    );
  }
}
```

Is anything wrong with this?

Comment: Find any solution to this?